# Querying middle data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been working with Firebase for a bit and I am trying to figure out how to query data that is in the middle of the child list.

Say, in a structure like the following, how could I retrieve the middle 2 values without limiting it to the first/last 3 and filtering out myself, which would slow down tremendously once there are more values and I needed to do something from the middle?

```
data: {
    id1: 12345,
    id2: 23515,
    id3, 68123,
    id4, 12303
}
```

In SQL I could just limit the row's index to `2 >= index <= 3` and that would work. `Id1-4` and the values are not my actual naming scheme, so I couldn't just query `id +` the one I want individually.

If the answer would be to make an index value and store it with it, how would I go about keeping the indexes unique and in increasing order?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: I'm aware of all those methods, but they still don't answer my question. I want to pick the middle items in an unordered list, and you can't use more than one limit so you can't limit to last 3 and then limit to first 2 to do what I wanted to accomplish in the example given.

Comment: There is no way to access items by their index in the Firebase API. But if you know the key of the child you want to start at, you can `orderByKey().startAt(key).limitToFirst(2)`. Unfortunately that's as specific as I can answer, given the broadness of the question.